# .htaccess AddType to parse html (weird behavior)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, add-type

I need my .html files to be processed as .php, so I added the following line to my .htaccess file:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .htm .html
```

It works greatly on wamp, but on production this weird thing happens.

If I let the server open the default page (by just typing domain.com), it will open the index.html and process it as php (good!). But if I run any .html file **directly** (i.e. domain.com/index.html or any other html file) it will not be processed as php.

I tried other combinations without success. For example:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php .html .htm
```

or

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php5 .php
```

or

```
RemoveHandler .html .htm
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .htm .html
```

or

```
<FilesMatch "\.html$">
    ForceType application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

I also removed all other .htaccess lines to make sure it's not a conflict.

My server is shared and runs on UNIX FreeBSD, with Apache. Any help is appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
AddHandler fcgid-script .htm .html
```

Or

```
AddHandler x-mapp-php5 .html .htm
```